# Combination of Stackview with GridLayout with QML and PySide6

Tags: python, qt, qml

I have the following small Application:

**main.py:**

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    # Get the path of the current directory, and then add the name
    # of the QML file, to load it.
    qml_file = Path(__file__).parent / "view.qml"
    engine.load(qml_file)

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

and the

**view.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: main
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    header: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            ToolButton {
                text: qsTr("GridView1")
                onClicked: stack.push(grid_1)
            }
            ToolButton {
                text: qsTr("GridView2")
                onClicked: stack.push(grid_2)
            }
        }
    }

    StackView {
        id: stack
        initialItem: grid_1
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Component {
        id: grid_1

        GridLayout {
            id: grid
            columns: 3
            columnSpacing: 0

            Rectangle {
                id: red_1
                width: parent.width/5
                height: parent.height
                color: "red"
                border.color: "black"
                border.width: 5
                radius: 10

                Text {
                    text: grid.width
                    anchors.centerIn: red_1
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: red_2
                width: parent.width*2/5
                height: parent.height/2
                color: "red"
                border.color: "green"
                border.width: 5
                radius: 10

                Text {
                    text: red_2.width
                    anchors.centerIn: red_2
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: red_3
                width: parent.width*2/5
                height: parent.height
                color: "red"
                border.color: "blue"
                border.width: 5
                radius: 10

                Text {
                    text: red_3.width
                    anchors.centerIn: red_3
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: grid_2

        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "green"
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 5
            radius: 10
        }
    }
}
```

Now we come to the issue:

After launch the Window should look like this:

[image]

But instead it looks like this:

[image]

It seems like that the rectangle `red_3` is stacked above the other rectangles. Only switching to `GridView2` resolves this issue. But this brings another issue on the plan:
While after a fresh restart of the Application a resizing of the Window results in a resizing of `red_3` as wanted. After Switching between `GridView2` and `GridView1` and the Application looks like as in figure 1, resizing the Window, does not effect the rectangles anymore. The Resizing takes only place after switching between the `GridViews`

From my perspective it looks like `InitialItem` does not load the GridLayout correctely and `push` destroys some event handling. Am I wrong or/and how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using `GridLayout`, you should use `Layout.preferredWidth` and `Layout.preferredHeight` instead of `width` and `height`. Here's critical edits you need to make to your `grid_1` component.

```
            Rectangle {
                id: red_1
                Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width/5
                Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height
                // ...
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: red_2
                Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width*2/5
                Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height/2
                // ...
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: red_3
                Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width*2/5
                Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height
                // ...
            }
```

However, because you are using Layouts, we can minimize the need for arithmetic in our geometry by using better Layout semantics such as `Layout.fillWidth: true` and `Layout.fillHeight: true`. In the case of the `Layout.fillWidth: true` because I also set `Layout.preferredWidth` to be 100, 200, 200 respectively it will achieve the 1/5, 2/5, 2/5 split you want.

```
            Rectangle {
                id: red_1
                Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                // ...
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: red_2
                Layout.preferredWidth: 200
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height/2
                // ...
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: red_3
                Layout.preferredWidth: 200
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                // ...
            }
```

I was able to run the above on pyside6 on Ubuntu 20 with
https://github.com/stephenquan/pyside-stackoverflow/tree/master/73640872

Comment: I switched my `width: <value>` and `height: <value>` entries with your suggestions. I understand why this is the better approach, but sadly resulted in the same issues I described above.

Comment: Really, but it worked for me - I ran your program in pyside with the changes and I got to see the proper result. If you need I can put it on github?

Comment: For comparison this would be nice. Is it maybe an issue with PySide6?

Comment: You are absolutly right. Was my mistake. Didn't switch the qml-file. So using height and width instead of the layout context breaks the events?

Comment: GridLayout, ColumnLayout, RowLayout are different to GridView, Column and Row. The former means you will leave up to Qt/QML to calculate all the placements for you. You give it enough hint via Layout attached properties and it takes care of the micro management. In contrast, the latter kinda gives you fine control which means you need to give it precise placement through a combination of anchoring, x, y, width and height. The pain point. Most of the time, it will yield unintended result - hence you're original issue.

Comment: So the actually mixing here (Stack**View** with Grid**Layout**) is the bigger issue? It Sounds not as a good idea to mix up those designpatterns.

Comment: You can mix carefully. For instance, Item, Rectangle, StackView can be sized using either method. The concern is those layout components GridView/Row/Column vs GridLayout/RowLayout/ColumnLayout. They dictate the immediate child needs to follow the appropriate rule respectively. It only applies to immediate child. Then it's fair game again. It's really hard to explain. You just going to have to explore yourself. You'll figure it out.