# Python PyQt6 (6.4.0) QML Difficulty in Applying Style to Qt.QWidgets

Tags: python, qml, pyqt6

I am in the research/education phase now, and am *not* seeing a lot of info on the web about applying a `Qml`-based style to `QWidgets`.  This implies it's difficult or not possible.  I doubt it's impossible, but I am curious what the options are for doing that?

Ideally, what I want to do is use the system (user-chosen) theme in my application.  I'm on Linux, and it uses GTK and GNOME for themes.  I want to support Linux in general (maybe one day, other platforms), so would like to make the app theme cross-distro.

I don't know if this is a tall order.  But, is it extremely involved to make PyQt6 QWidgets styled from a QML style?  Can widgets use the system theme?

Comment: There is no info because QML and Qt widgets are two very distinct ways of providing the UI, and by default their appearance is completely different, both in concept and implementation. So, you cannot "style" widgets "as QML". OTOH, some QtQuick controls can look similarly to Qt widgets as long as they use the same style (if that style is available for both systems), such as the "Fusion" style. That, said, and especially for Linux, appearance completely depends on the computer: by default, Qt widgets do **not** look the same as Gnome widgets, unless the required modules are installed.

Comment: This means that you can never be 100% sure of system theme consistency in other's computers. That's how Linux works. For instance, I use fluxbox, and there is absolutely no way to make Qt apps "look native" (it wouldn't even make sense); and frankly, I wouldn't care less. I'm afraid you are worrying too much about appearance right now, and sooner or later you'll probably realize that you shouldn't put too much concerns on this.

Comment: Alright, thanks @musicamante.  I'm fairly new to Linux, and am learning.  I want to devote *some* attention to app styling, so, my distro only supports two QStyles: Fusion (all Linux distros do, I'm sure) and Windows.  I want to make all styles available to the app.  So, I will look into including the full range of `qtstyleplugins` files.  Do you know of a precompiled link to that branch?  I can't seem to find a link.  My distro has Qt5, but I'm on Qt6 (PyQt6).  Or, I'm mixed up and need to read more...

Comment: I hear ya though, musicamante.  Get core PyQt skills up, then worry about styling.  I just got bitten by the bug.  So, now I'm exploring my OS to see what's available.  But, I would need to include the styles and themes with my app when it goes public.  So, that opens a whole can of worms...

Comment: Yes, you need to be patient and read more. The two styles you're referring to are provided by Qt (they are the default ones on Linux). Also, the styles included in `qtstyleplugins` are only available for Qt5 and I sincerely doubt they will be ported to Qt6, especially considering that they are based on the looks of **old** legacy/obsolete toolkits (motif, gtk2), making them useless, as inconsistent with most modern systems. Also, unless you plan to use fully sandboxed installs, you'll be relying on what the OS provides, and you can do absolutely nothing about that. Btw, that's not a bug.

Comment: You have me dead to rights on being patient.  I tend to post (against guidelines) without having done exhaustive research.  I will attempt to curtail that in the future.  Heck, I've posted 3 questions that, 10 minutes later, I solved myself (promptly hiding the questions).  Anywho, I don't think I want to sandbox my app totally.  It's just all the variation in distros and platforms...  re: `qtstyleplugins`: they are shipped with Qt6—I have a lone plugin on my distro (Adwaita), which works in my app.  I think some are Qt5-only, while others are available for Qt6.

Comment: Each installed Qt major version has its own plugins (they are not compatible, as they are compiled against the Qt build), you cannot put a style built for Qt5 in Qt6 styles. The Adwaita style you see isn't provided by Qt and was probably automatically installed by your distro (as said, they only include "fusion" and "windows" styles). And you cannot bundle it in your program because plugins are compiled against the specific Qt version they're used on: while the program could theoretically work if you have Qt6.2 and the user has Qt6.3, it will crash trying to "include" the foreign theme.

Comment: Just so that you know, PyQt isn't the only python-qt solution out there. There is PySide. It's worth checking out. The other thing to point out is QWidget base UI is on the way out. You want to look at QtQuick2 UI instead. Sometime back I answered a question related to pyside here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73640872/combination-of-stackview-with-gridlayout-with-qml-and-pyside6/73642634#73642634 which works fine on Ubuntu. Full source to that answer was posted here https://github.com/stephenquan/pyside-stackoverflow/tree/master/73640872

Comment: Alright, fellas.  Thanks!  I think with my own ongoing research, and the information provided here, I have enough to go on.  I would need to, as musicamante said, sandbox my app with a self-compiled version of Qt 6.4 to have complete control.  Doesn't strike me as worth it.  There's always `styleSheet()`'s.  @Stephen Quan, PySide is essentially the same thing as PyQt6, in my research.  I don't know if a refactor is worth it.  I'll check out those links though.  Could be some golden nuggets in there.